# Remove the [play-mvc] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

Yesterday I noticed an large amount of [playframework](/questions/tagged/playframework) questions hit the first page of the *active* tab. They all got edited by the same user.

In about **20 minutes**, the user retagged **over 40 questions** with [play-mvc](/questions/tagged/play-mvc). It very much looks like the user just strives for an easy [taxonomist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11/taxonomist) badge (do self edited questions even count for this?).

Anyways, the [play-mvc](/questions/tagged/play-mvc) tag is useless and redundant. Play is already a MVC framework and there is no thing called "play-mvc". Most tagged questions aren't even about MVC in any particular.

The play-mvc wiki is just a reworded version of the playframework wiki and provides no additional information. Again, I think this was done just so the user could [get the tag-editor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/254/tag-editor?userid=675552).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Want me to synonymize it? So far *every* question with [play-mvc](/questions/tagged/play-mvc) is also tagged [playframework](/questions/tagged/playframework), which confirms its redundancy even further.

Comment: Do it, the tag wiki he created for it explicitly says "Play Framework" - so, useless tag.